# Is it possible to substitute a function definition into a sympy expression?

Tags: function, sympy, symbolic-math

Suppose I define a sympy function `f` and I have the expression `f(5) * f(2)`. Is it possible to substitute a function of my choice for f and evaluate the above expression? For example, lets say I choose f(x) to be x**2. Then, the above expression would return 100.

The only way I know how to do this is the following code:

```
x = sp.symbols('x')
F = sp.Function('F')
expr = F(2)*F(5)
expr = expr.subs({F(2):4,F(5):25}) #my bad solution
expr #prints out 100
```

But this becomes very difficult to do when the function has to be evaluated at many points, or if you do not know the values beforehand. What is the better way to do the above substitutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with subs or replace depending on what type of function your are providing:

```py
from sympy import *
f = Function('f')
eq = f(2)*f(5)
eq.subs(f, cos)
# cos(2)*cos(5)
g = lambda x: 1/(x + 1)
eq.replace(lambda x: x.func == f, lambda x: g(x.args[0]))
# 1/18
```